# Running Joomla locally from xampp?

Tags: joomla

I downloaded a Joomla installation from a server and want to run it locally from xampp. I installed the database and modified the configuration.php to match my local settings.

Now when I call the local URL, it tells me that the connection to localhost was interrupted (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET). It finds the local database because when I change the database name in the config file, it tells me it cant find the database.

Do I have to make changes in the database as well, or maybe at some other place to run it locally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the following things when you are migrating Joomla sites.

It seems DB unable to connect you must check DB name and user details.

Make sure configuration.php is writable.

```
public $dbtype = 'mysqli'; //which dB type you are using
public $host = 'localhost'; // normally keep as it is
public $user = 'user name'; // DB user name
public $password = 'password'; // DB password
public $db = 'db name';//DB name
public $log_path = '/joomla/logs';//log path your local path
public $tmp_path = '/joomla/tmp'; //temp path if its not correct you can't install plugins.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think those settings are correct. As I said, I am pretty sure it finds the database. As soon as I change my db settings, it tells me it could not connect. Changing them back to my correct local db settings, removes the Joomla "could not connect" message. Now the browser (Chrome) tells me it cant connect (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET).

I also installed a plain Joomla locally which worked instantly and compared the settings, they both look ok. Maybe there is something hidden in the database itself? Some path that must be changed in some table?

Comment: check you php_max_execution time.

Comment: The execution time was set to 10000 so that cant be it, the other topic did not solve it, too.

Comment: Try changing localhost to 127.0.0.1.